# React Redux not re-rendering when Store changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have been trying to figure this out for a day now.

I think I have set up everything correctly, however, the view does not re-render nor the prop updates. However, I can see the change in Redux Developer tools. I know there are other questions like this on Stackoverflow but none of them really helps me.

Am I not seeing something?

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Store from './store';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(Store,  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
//actions.js
const initPurchases = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: "INITILIZE_PURCHASES",
        payload
    }
}

module.exports = {
    initPurchases,
}
```

```
// store.js

const initalState = {
    inventory: [],
}

const rootReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "INITILIZE_PURCHASES":
            state.purchases = [...action.payload];
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}

export default rootReducer
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import actions from './actions';


class App extends React.Component {
    state = {}

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getPurchases();
    }


    getPurchases = async () => {
        // call to api which returns t
        this.props.initPurchases(t)
    }   

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.purchases) // Returns empty array []

        return (
            <div className="App">
                // Some view
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => {return {purchases: state.purchases}},
    actions,
)(App);
```

[Logs from React Redux Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KgNq.png)

Can somebody please help me? I can't figure out what's wrong here. I ommited most of the things that i are not related to my problem (at least I do not think they are). I can upload the entire repo to github to see the bigger context

Comment: Hi Ali, I am pretty new to Redux but don't you have to return  in reducer case

" return state.purchases = [...action.payload];
            break;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducer needs to return the new state, otherwise the state remains unchanged:

```
const rootReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "INITILIZE_PURCHASES":
            return { ...state, purchases: [...action.payload] };
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this.  You have to return a new state, which copies fields from the previous state using the spread operator, then new fields to be added to the right of the object so that they overwrite values in the previous state

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I was mutating the state?

Comment: Indeed, you were mutating the state

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement something like:

```
import actions from './actions'

...

class App extends React.Component {

   ...

   componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.initPurchases();
   }

   render() {
     ...
   }

}


const mapDispatchToApp = (dispatch) => (
  {
    initPurchases: () => (
      dispatch(actions.initPurchases())
    ),
  }
)

...

export default connect(
    (state) => {return {purchases: state.purchases}},
    mapDispatchToApp,
)(App);
```

This is because you need to `dispatch` actions to the store

Comment: I don't think this was the problem. The solution above fixed it. I think I was mutating the state